# Is "Me vs Me" grammatically correct?

Tags: pronouns, reflexives, subject-or-object

What I want to say is that I compete with myself in short.

I was thinking that it could be

- Me vs Me
- I vs Me
- I vs Myself

Which one is grammatically correct?

Comment: For some reason, I want to render this as "Me _vs._ Myself". I'm not convinced that there is any sort of relevant grammar associated with "_A_ vs. _B_" usages.

Comment: Orwell says, essentially, 'Never say anything outlandish in English, no matter how grammatical / ungrammatical the string you are thinking about is.'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**"me vs. myself"**

---

Versus, from Latin [**vers**](https://www.bing.com/search?q=define%20versus&pc=MOZI&form=MOZLBR), or versa, means facing or towards (imagine two pieces of wood lying *against* each other). The implication is of *competing interests*, of which one would "prevail," generally speaking, in a match-up or some [figure of merit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figure_of_merit) competition.

The construction is [noun/noun phrase] vs. [noun/noun phrase].

> It's **shirts** versus **skins**.
>
> It was **him** versus **the world**.
>
> When it comes to stopping procrastination, it's really **me** versus **myself**. (or *me vs me*, see below)

**It could also be "*me vs me*,"** in my opinion, but the [reflexive pronoun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_pronoun) ([also this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_verb)) "*myself*" adds value here as it helps establish that the action "has the same semantic agent and patient" (that is, the 'direct object,' after a fashion, is the same as its subject). "Me vs me" might have heightened comedic effect as it seems schizophrenic in a sense.

Comment: Thank you! After reading your explanation I clearly understand. English is not my first language and I have to be careful. Otherwise, I will sound outlandish as Edwin Ashworth said on his comment.

Comment: Thanks, glad to have helped